# Pass model data from view but not display in action using MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in MVC Architechture. I want to pass data of Model to action but I don't know how to pass it.

I thought it passes model data automatically when I execute following code.

`View of ShoppingController:`

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MakePayment", "Shopping", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnBegin = "VarifyParameters" }))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                First Name *
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.firstName, new { @id = "txtFName", @class = "text-field" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Last Name *
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.lastName, new { @id = "txtLName", @class = "text-field" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Make Payment" onclick="makePayment()" />
            </td>
        <tr>
    <table>
    //there are more button here with different functionalities
 }


//javascript
 function VarifyParameters() {
 try {
        return false;
  } catch (e) {

    }
  }
```

I doesn't get any data in action. How can I pass all model data to action by javascript

```
//checkoutController  
public ActionResult MakePayment(PaymentDetails paymentDetails)
{
     //paymentDetails are always null
}
```

Can anybody suggest me how to pass the model data?

Comment: You need to submit a form to a `[HttpPost]` method - all your doing is a redirect and not passing anything to the method. Suggest you go to the MVC sire and work through the tutorials to learn the basics.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know the concept of Submit. But I want to check few validation using javascript on button click event. Then I want to call the action. I don't know how to manage flow in this case.

Comment: What validation. And why aren't you using the built in validation features of MVC? All you code is doing is a redirect.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know in built validations. But I have a situation where I must call a function which check few validations and decide flow before this form submit.

Comment: Clearly you don't know. Use a `RemoteAttribute` if you really need to call a server method

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you please suggest me link of flow for RemoteAttribute? Let me tell you in detail, I have a javascript function which checks some conditions. If conditions don't satisfied, form should not submitted. If conditions get satisfied, form should submit. (Anyhow I must call javascript function). Can you please suggest me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118426/discussion-between-nanji-mange-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: You have to use   `@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @areas = "Admin", @class = "form-horizontal fill-up", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {` On your `.cshtml` page.  Refer this link : https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `Html.BeginForm` and changing your button type to `submit` :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MakePayment", "Shopping"))
    {
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                First Name *
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.firstName, new { @id = "txtFName", @class = "text-field" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Last Name *
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.lastName, new { @id = "txtLName", @class = "text-field" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Make Payment" />
            </td>
        <tr>
    <table>
    }
```

And you have to add `[HttpPost]` to your controller:

```
//checkoutController
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult MakePayment(PaymentDetails paymentDetails)
{
     //your code
}
```

You can also use `Ajax.BeginForm` and you can use its `OnBegin`, `OnSuccess`, `OnFailure` functions. Like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MakePayment", "Shopping", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnBegin = "VarifyParameters" }))
            {

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    First Name *
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.firstName, new { @id = "txtFName", @class = "text-field" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstName)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Last Name *
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.lastName, new { @id = "txtLName", @class = "text-field" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastName)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Make Payment" />
                </td>
            <tr>
        <table>

}
```

But while using ajax, don't forget to add `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` reference in your view.

Comment: Thank you but I have a javascript function `VarifyParameters()` (it check validations) which need to call on button click.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can use your VarifyParameters() function with Ajax.BeginForm's "OnBegin" attribute.

Comment: Thank you. What I understand is form will not submitted if VarifyParameters() returns false. Let me know if I am getting wrong.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, if your VarifyParameters() function returns false, the form will not submitted.

Comment: I have added this script in View: `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/query.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` but it doesn't call VarifyParameters function.

Comment: It skips the call and call the action in controller.

Comment: @Url.Content("~/Scripts/query.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" has an incorrect syntax, it should be "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118429/discussion-between-nanji-mange-and-kkakkurt).

Comment: Yes. Now it verify the parameters but it still call action even `VarifyParameters()` returns false. I have updated my code in question as you suggested. Can you please tell me if I am missing something?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your VarifyParameters() function. You can update your question with its codes.

Comment: I have tried by blank function as I have updated in my question. just created function and return it to false. You can see in my question.

Comment: Are you using VarifyParameters() in that way or with <script></script> tags? You have to use it betweetn <script> tags in view.

Comment: Of course. All is working fine except this. It should stop in case if VarifyParameters returns false. Is it fine with @using (Ajax.BeginFor.. line? Is there anything like Asynchronous call here?

Comment: `VarifyParameters()` function is working fine. I have tried by debugger.

Comment: Anyways, I have returned that call from action. Thank you so much for your support.